# postgreSQL отфильтровать id используя exists и @> двух массивов

Tags: sql, postgresql

вопрос не совсем точно отражает суть, поэтому постараюсь объяснить, что не получается. Есть 2 таблицы, одна называется **countries**, вторая **sets**.

**countries** выглядит так

`| county_id | country_code |
 |    1      |     ru       |
 |    2      |     es       |
 |    3      |     jp       |
 ...`

**sets** так

```
| set_id | country_id | is_used | group |
|   1    |      1     |    0    |   1   |
|   2    |      1     |    1    |   1   |
|   3    |      1     |    1    |   2   |
|   4    |      1     |    0    |   1   |
|   5    |      1     |    1    |   2   |
|   6    |      1     |    1    |   1   |
|   7    |      1     |    0    |   1   |
|   8    |      1     |    0    |   1   |
|   9    |      2     |    0    |   1   |
|   10   |      2     |    0    |   2   |
...
```

в запрос будет передаваться 2 массива, допустим [1, 2, 3] и [4, 5, 6](значения передаваемые в первом и втором массиве никогда не совпадают, т.е. одного и того же числа не может быть в обоих массивах),
нужно построить запрос:

```
SELECT country_id FROM countries 
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM sets 
  WHERE sets.country_id = countries.country_id *тут продолжение запроса, который не могу составить*)
```

,где будет учитываться наличие всех **set_id** в первом массиве и всех **set_id** во втором, но колонка group подходящих **set_id** к одному и второму должна быть обязательно разной, т.е.:

Если первый массив

> [1, 2, 3]

, то нужно проверить, все ли **set_id** есть и все имеют **group** одинаковый(будь то 1 или 2)

Второй массив

> [4, 5, 6]

, тоже проверяет есть ли все **set_id** у этого **country_id**, которые подходят под массив, **НО** они должны быть в группе противоположной, той, которая у первого массива. Если условия не выполняются или какой то элемент из массивов не найден ИЛИ значение **is_used** у этой строки = 0, то *exists* должен вернуть *false*.

Попытался объяснить суть задачи развернуто, надеюсь не запутал вас ещё больше.

Comment: *нужно проверить, все ли set_id есть и все имеют group одинаковый(будь то 1 или 2)* это `COUNT(set_id)=array.length` и `COUNT(DISTINCT set_id)=1` соответственно. *они должны быть в группе противоположной, той, которая у первого массива* противоположной - это не равной, что ли? ну это что-то вроде `MAX(set_id_1)!=MAX(set_id_2)` (при условии, что предыдущие проверки обеих групп дали True, а если нет, и там есть хоть одно False, то не пофиг ли). Ну а всю подготовку проводим в `WITH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал запрос таким образом, не думаю что он показатель оптимизированного запроса, но в моём случае он будет выполнятся не часто и не будет узким местом.

```
SELECT countries.country_id
FROM countries
LEFT JOIN (SELECT country_id, array_agg(set_id) arr FROM sets WHERE sets.is_used = true AND sets.group = 1 GROUP BY country_id) ft ON(countries.country_id = ft.country_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT country_id, array_agg(set_id) arr FROM sets WHERE sets.is_used = true AND sets.group = 2 GROUP BY country_id) tt ON(countries.country_id = tt.country_id)
WHERE (ft.arr @> ARRAY[73] AND tt.arr @> ARRAY[86]) OR (ft.arr @> ARRAY[86] AND tt.arr @> ARRAY [73])
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения:

```
WITH select_1 AS (SELECT country_id, group, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY group) FROM sets WHERE set_id IN (1,2,3) AND is_used <> 0),
select_2 AS (SELECT country_id, group, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY group) FROM sets WHERE set_id IN (4,5,6) AND is_used <> 0)
SELECT countries.country_id FROM countries  
JOIN select_1 ON select_1.country_id = countries.country_id AND select_1.count = 3--3 - размер массива
JOIN select_2 ON select_2.country_id = countries.country_id AND select_2.count = 3--3 - размер массива
WHERE select_1.group <> select_2.group
```

ПС Валидность запроса не проверял, но надеюсь подтолкнет вас в правильном направлении